# Python Invalid Snytax

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code I have been working on.

The very last line `write_csv('twitter_gmail.csv', messages, append=True)` throws a

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-164 ~]$ ./twitter_test16.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./twitter_test16.sh", line 53, in 
    write_csv('twitter_gmail.csv', messages, append=True)
NameError: name 'messages' is not defined

I have messages defined so I dont understand why it would do that.

```
import csv
import json
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib
import sys
import requests
import time

CONSUMER_KEY = "
CONSUMER_SECRET = "
ACCESS_KEY = "
ACCESS_SECRET = "
class TwitterSearch:
    def __init__(self, ckey=CONSUMER_KEY, csecret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                 akey=ACCESS_KEY, asecret=ACCESS_SECRET,
                 query='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.{mode}?{query}'
                 ):
        consumer     = oauth.Consumer(key=ckey, secret=csecret)
        access_token = oauth.Token(key=akey, secret=asecret)
        self.client  = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)
        self.query   = query

    def search(self, q, mode='json', **queryargs):
        queryargs['q'] = q
        query = urllib.urlencode(queryargs)
        return self.client.request(self.query.format(query=query, mode=mode))

def write_csv(fname, rows, header=None, append=False, **kwargs):
    filemode = 'ab' if append else 'wb'
    with open(fname, filemode) as outf:
        out_csv = csv.writer(outf, **kwargs)
        if header:
            out_csv.writerow(header)
        out_csv.writerows(rows)

def main():
    ts = TwitterSearch()
    response, data = ts.search('@gmail.com', result_type='recent')
    js = json.loads(data)

    messages = ([msg['created_at'], msg['txt'], msg['user']['id']] \
                for msg in js.get('statuses', []))

write_csv('twitter_gmail.csv', messages, append=True)
```

Comment: why did you just change the text to get rid of the syntax error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The previous line is missing a parenthesis.

`messages = ([msg['created_at'], msg['txt'], msg['user']['id']] for msg in js.get('statuses', [])`

Should be:

`messages = ([msg['created_at'], msg['txt'], msg['user']['id']] for msg in js.get('statuses', []))`

I'm surprised that it works when you change to print? Are you also changing the comprehension when you do that?

You asked why the line number of the error was after the bad syntax?

Try putting this in line one of a file and running it, and note the line of the `SyntaxError`.

`a = (]`

Then try this and check out the line number:

```
a = (
b = "some stuff"
```

Finally, try this:

```
a = (




b = "some stuff"
```

Think about when you would know that the programmer had made a python-illegal typo if you were reading the code and carrying it out via pen and paper.

Basically, a `SyntaxError` is raised as soon as it can be unambiguously determined that invalid syntax was used, which is often immediately after a statement where a mistake was made, not immediately at.

You'll frequently get line numbers on `SyntaxErrors` that are a line (or several lines if there's empty lines or a corner case) below the actual typo.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  It totally resolved that error.

Comment: IT gives me now a 
  File "./twitter_test16.sh", line 53, in <module>
    write_csv('twitter_gmail.csv', messages, append=True)
NameError: name 'messages' is not defined

Comment: I I have messages defined above so I am not sure why it would do that.

Comment: Python raises the error as soon as it detects a token that is at odds with what it has so far parsed. Line 53 had the first token that allowed the interpreter to know there was a problem with the syntax.

Comment: So why is it telling me "messages" is not defined.  Is it because I am parsing it wrong?

Comment: I don't think the posted code should produce that exception. I might post the exception and the new code in a different thread to get an answer to that. You should get a `NameError` when you use a variable that hasn't been defined in the current scope, but `messages` is defined at the only place it is used in the posted snippet.